# Extract size dimensions from a string using PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

Can someone help me to extract dimensions from a string similar to thse strings

```
Extending Garden Table 100 x 200 x 300 cm white
Extending Garden Table 200 x 200 cm black
Extending Garden Table 200 cm black Large
```

i need it to only ouput **100 x 200 x 300 cm**   or **200 x 200 cm** or **200 cm**,  according what the string  contains

I started with below code in case it could help a bit

```
$string1 = "Extending Garden Table 100 x 200 x 300 cm white"; 
$test    = get_dimensions($string1);  //need it to output 100 x 200 x 300 cm


function get_dimensions($str) {
    preg_match_all('/[0-9]{1,2}\X[0-9]{1,2}/i', $str, $matches);
    //preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
    return $matches;
}
```

Comment: Is there always `cm` word after the last dimension value?

Comment: not always.  i just created a function to enter variables as  "cm"  "m"  "L"  "kg"  etc..     if you have an idea if these "allowed" units can be implemented from the regex, that would be great!

Comment: Yes, see [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/4WtdL).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks alot you are amazing i appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
\d+(?:\s*x\s*\d+)*\s*cm\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2295h3/1/). *Details*:

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\s*x\s*\d+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `\s*x\s*` - `x` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
  - `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `cm` - a `cm` word
- `\b` - a word boundary

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/auSRn):

```php
function get_dimensions($str) {
    preg_match_all('/\d+(?:\s*x\s*\d+)*\s*cm\b/i', $str, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}
$string1 = "Extending Garden Table 100 x 200 x 300 cm white"; 
$test    = get_dimensions($string1);  //need it to output 100 x 200 x 300 cm
print_r($test);
// => Array ( [0] => 100 x 200 x 300 cm )
```

To extract numbers with fractional part, add `(?:[,.]\d+)?` (an optional occurrence of a comma or dot and then one or more digits) after each `\d+` in the pattern above:

```php
\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?(?:\s*x\s*\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)*\s*cm\b
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2295h3/3).

Comment: thanks alot for helping thats exactly what i needed,   do you also have a way to handle some with decimals?  like  1.3 x 2.5 x 3.5 m

Comment: @inventor Yes, `\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?(?:\s*x\s*\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)*\s*cm\b`